# FragmentTransaction setCustomAnimations() animates only the next fragment but not current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I am working on navigating between two fragments with slide in and out animation.

So when I click on an item in FirstFragment, it will go to SecondFragment.

When I move to the SecondFragmnet, I want the FirstFragment to slide out to left and the SecondFragment to slide in from right.

When I pop back to the FirstFragment, I want the FirstFragment to slide in from left and the SecondFragment to slide out from left to right.

So here is my FragmentTransaction code

```
val secondFragment = SecondFragment()

activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.let {
  it.setCustomAnimations(
      R.anim.enter_right_to_left,
      R.anim.exit_right_to_left,
      R.anim.enter_left_to_right,
      R.anim.exit_left_to_right
   )
   it.add(R.id.fragmentContainerView, secondFragment)
   it.addToBackStack(FirstFragment.TAG)
   it.commit()
}
```

These are the anim xml files

enter_right_to_left.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

exit_right_to_left.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

enter_left_to_right.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

exit_left_to_right.xml

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%" />
```

When I execute the code, only the SecondFragment animates while the FirstFragment does not animate but just stays there. One thing I found is that if I change `it.add(R.id.fragmentContainerView, secondFragment)` to `it.replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, secondFragment)` It works fine as expected. However, I need to keep the FirstFragment so I need to use `add()` instead of `replace()`. Do you have any ideas why the FirstFragment does not animate with `add()` please?

Comment: If you need to "keep" `FirstFragment`, then it isn't going to animate out. Which way do you want it?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you very much for a quick response. So, do I need to use replace() to animate the FirstFragment because I don't want to remove and recreate the FirstFragment? That's why I used ```add()``` instead of ```replace()```

Comment: Well, an `add` doesn't change any other fragments. It just adds a new Fragment, overlapping any existing fragments. Is that what you want? If not, then `add` isn't what you should be using.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I think that's what I want. I want to add the SecondFragment, overlapping the existing FirstFragment but with a bit of animation. So you say setCustomAnimations() would not apply to the existing FirstFragment if I use add() please?

Comment: You've done nothing in your `FragmentTransaction` that affects FirstFragment, so it is entirely unaffected by your `FragmentTransaction`. The animations you're using make it seem like you want FirstFragment to slide off the screen, not continue to existing underneath your SecondFragment (which is what `add` does).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Okay sure, so if I want to animate the FirstFragment which stays underneath the SecondFragment, then I need to animate it with ObjectAnimator or something, I can't just rely on the FragmentTransaction. Is that so please?